# infix properties of operators in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've done a [Haskell library](https://github.com/stla/mpolynomials) allowing to manipulate multivariate polynomials. It uses some instances defined by the **numeric-prelude** library, e.g. an additive group instance. The addition for this instance is denoted `+` in this library. I find this a bit annoying because there's already the usual `+` for numbers, so I defined:

```haskell
import Algebra.Additive as AlgAdd

(^+^) :: Polynomial a -> Polynomial a -> Polynomial a
(^+^) p q = p AlgAdd.+ q
```

But it seems to me that by doing that, the "infix properties" of `+` are lost. I never dealt with the infix properties, and I have a couple of questions. I want to keep the same infix properties.

1. Looking at [the code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude-0.4.4/docs/src/Algebra.Additive.html#%2B) I see this line:

   ```
   infixl 6  +, -
   ```

This line is isolated, at the beginning of the code. So should I similarly include the line

```
infixl 6 ^+^, ^-^
```

at the beginning of my code? In [this blog post](https://bugfactory.io/blog/custom-infix-operators-in-haskell/) the author defines the infix property of a function just before defining this function. Is it another, equivalent way to proceed? And is it not possible to do something like `(^+^) = (AlgAdd.+)` in such a way that the infix properties are automatically copied?

2. Still looking at the code, I see:

   ```
   {-# MINIMAL zero, (+), ((-) | negate) #-}
   ```

What does that mean?

3. I'm also wondering how to define the opposite of a polynomial. I have the substraction `p ^-^ q` but how to define `^-^ p`?
4. Finally, when the package author defines the instance e.g. for `Double`, he/she writes:

   ```
   instance C Double  where
     {-# INLINE zero #-}
     {-# INLINE negate #-}
     {-# INLINE (+) #-}
     {-# INLINE (-) #-}
     zero   = P.fromInteger 0
     negate = P.negate
     (+)    = (P.+)
     (-)    = (P.-)
   ```

What is the purpose of `INLINE`?

Comment: Questions 2, 3, and 4 should be asked separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can write the infix declaration above the definition, but it's not a requirement.

   ```
   infixl 6 ^+^, ^-^

   (^+^) :: Polynomial a -> Polynomial a -> Polynomial a
   (^+^) = (AlgAdd.+)
   ```

   The infix properties cannot be copied.
2. The [`Minimal` pragma](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/pragmas.html#minimal-pragma) refers to the "minimal set of methods that must be defined" for a class definition to be total. In your case it means you can either write a definition for the methods "`zero` and `(+)` and `(-)`" or "`zero` and `(+)` and `negate`" since you can define `negate` in terms of the first group

   ```hs
   negate a = zero - a
   ```

   and `(-)` in terms of the second. So it doesn't matter which one you define.

   ```hs
   n - m = n + negate m
   ```
3. Not sure.
4. The [`Inline` pragma](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/pragmas.html#inline-and-noinline-pragmas) forces ghc to inline (unfold) the definition. Here is the answer to [Is there ever a reason to not mark a monadic bind operator `(>>=)` as inline?](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/odw669/is_there_ever_a_reason_to_not_mark_a_monadic_bind/)

Comment: Thank you. For 3) I mean there is the substraction, as for numbers, `x - y`, and there is the opposite `- x = 0 - x`. I'm wondering how to define the 'opposite' operator?

Comment: The opposite operator would be `negate` wouldn't it? Normally an operator takes two argument so that wouldn't be a operator unless you use the [`PostfixOperators` extension](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/rebindable_syntax.html#extension-PostfixOperators). This lets you define `(-.) = negate` written parenthesised: `(x -.)`.

Comment: Yes, this is `negate`. Thanks again.

Comment: Re: (3) the negation operation `-foo` is special built-in syntax; it's not possible for users to define their own prefix operators. You can use `RebindableSyntax` to give it a different meaning, but you can only have one meaning per module that way.

Answer (score 2):

Without a fixity declaration, your operators `^+^` and `^-^` will behave as if declared with

```
infixl 9 ^+^, ^-^
```

that is, left-associative with extremely high precedence. If you want them to behave more or less like "regular" addition and subtraction, then you should explicitly declare them to have precedence level 6 with

```
infixl 6 ^+^, ^-^
```

The associativity and precedence levels are not "transferable" from another operator; you'll just have to look up the behavior of the operator you want to be similar to and declare yours appropriately.